# classic asp - cdonts

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using classic asp and cdonts on a Windows Server 2003 machine.

But I'm guessing the SMTP service needs to be running. Unfortunately it's asking for teh SP1 disk...which apparently has gone missing. I'm guessing not but is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CDO instead of CDONTS, that way you *can* specify an external SMTP server. See for instance this [article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-send-e-mail-with-cdo.html) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp) (look for remote server sample). CDONTS has been discontinued on win2K and later.